# Unit test method with Silex\Application as parameter

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, silex

In my project I have a class SessionManager which sets and clears session variables for sticky forms etc. Every method in that class takes in a Silex\Application object as parameter. How can I unit test these methods? Create a Silex application object in each test method? 
I'm new to Silex and unit testing so and not sure how to handle this.

Example of one method:

```
public static function setMessage($message, $messageClass, Application &$app)
{
    // store message as array, with content and class keys
    $app['session']->set('message', array(
        'content' => $message,
        'class' => $messageClass
    ));
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to pass the entire application? Its seems the pattern is not really good. You should may be just pass the service/class you need to use in your setMessage. In your case you should pass the session class. About the unit testing, if the injection is a "complex" class, then you should consider to use mock data provided by phpunit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly I think that `$app` should not be a dependency of your SessionManager; `$app['session']` should be. But also it should be a dependency of the *object* (ie: passed to the constructor) not of the individual method.

But that doesn't change the tactic for solving the problem. All you need to do is create a mock of the Session, which covers the dependent method you need to call, eg:

```
// in your test class
// ...
public function setup(){
    $mockedSession = $this->getMockedSession();
    $this->sessionManager = new SessionManager($mockedSession);
}

public function testMessage(){
    // test stuff here
}

private function getMockedSession(){
    $mockedSession = $this->getMockBuilder('\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['set'])
        ->getMock();

    $mockedSession->method('set')
        ->willReturn('something testable');

    return $mockedSession;
}
```

You probably only need to test that your `setMessage` method passes through its `$message` and `$messageClass` values to the mocked method: that's all it's doing. In this light you probably wanna have a `->with('message', [$testMessage, $testClass])` or something in your mock too. The exact implementation is down to how you want to test.